# Does AWS support the Oracle Autonomous Database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Does AWS have an engine to support Oracle's Autonomous Database?

https://www.oracle.com/in/database/autonomous-database/feature.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a 100% Oracle Public Cloud offering natively integrated with its 2nd generation IaaS.

Oracle also announced to deliver this on-prem with its Cloud at Customer delivery model in 2019.

More details here: https://www.oracle.com/openworld/on-demand.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot directly run Oracle Autonomous Database within AWS. However, while Oracle Autonomous Database is not locally available in other Clouds (such as AWS, Azure, etc.), you can **certainly** use Oracle Autonomous Database **from within those Clouds**. For example, instead of deploying Oracle Autonomous Database locally in AWS, Azure, or GCP, you can simply connect to Oracle Autonomous Database deployed in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. Several companies do this today. The multi-cloud approach is actually quite popular, especially among organizations that want to leverage the modern, high-performance, low/no maintenance database technology with their existing infrastructure located in non-Oracle clouds.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Autonomous Database is not supported on any other cloud providers like AWS, Azure, GCP, etc.
AWS has RDS for Oracle and it does provide some automation in terms of provisioning, backups, software patching, monitoring etc.
However, RDS for Oracle is not autonomous as the autonomous database offerings in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. This is one of the key differentiators of OCI.
You can easily connect your apps in AWS with an Autonomous database in OCI though.